# Any possibility to store the content of each page end into a separate file

Tags: pageend, finding

My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

Deep learning has transformed computer vision, natural language and speech processing in particular, and artificial intelligence in general. From a bag of semi-discordant tricks, none of which worked satisfactorily on real-life problems, artificial intelligence has become a formidable tool to solve real problems faced by industry, at scale. This is nothing short of a revolution going on under our very noses. To lead the curve of this revolution, it is imperative to understand the underlying principles and abstractions rather than simply memorizing the ``how-to'' steps of some hands-on guide. This is where mathematics comes in.

\section{First Level Head}

In this first chapter, we present an overview of deep learning. This will require us to use some concepts explained in subsequent chapters. Don't worry if there are some open questions at the end of this chapter: it is aimed at orienting your mind toward this difficult subject. As individual concepts become clearer in subsequent chapters, you should consider coming back and re-reading this chapter.

For instance, a cat's brain is often trying to choose between the following options:
\emph{run away} from the object in front of it vs.
\emph{ignore} the object in front of it vs. \emph{approach} the
object in front of it and purr. The cat's brain makes that decision
by processing sensory inputs like the perceived \emph{hardness} of
the object in front of it, the perceived \emph{sharpness} of the
object in front of it,  and so on.


This is an instance of a \emph{classification} problem, where the output is one of a set of possible classes.

Some other examples of classification problems in life are as follows:
\begin{itemize}
\item \emph{Buy} vs. \emph{hold} vs. \emph{sell}
a certain stock, from inputs like the
\emph{price history of this stock} and the
\emph{change in price of the stock in recent times}

\item Object recognition (from an image):
\begin{itemize}
\item Is this a car or a giraffe?
\item Is this a human or a non-human?
\item Is this an inanimate object or a living object?
\item Face recognition---is this Tom or Dick or Mary or Einstein or Messi?
\end{itemize}
\item Action recognition from a video:
\begin{itemize}
\item Is this person running or not running?
\item Is this person picking something up or not?
\item Is this person doing something violent or not?
\end{itemize}
\item Natural language processing (NLP) from digital documents:
\begin{itemize}
\item Does this news article belong to the realm of politics or sports?
\item Does this query phrase match a particular article in the archive?
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Second Level Head}

Another instance of quantitative estimation is estimating a house's price based on inputs like current income of the house's owner, crime statistics for the neighborhood, and so on.
Machines that make such quantitative estimators are called \textit{regressors}.

\end{document}
```

First page ended with the text `in the archive?`

[image]

Is there any possible to capture each and every page end text into a separate output file, example:

Page 1 ended with `in the archive?`

Page 2 ended with `..so and so...`

Kindly advise

Comment: I would just generate the pdf as usual then  use a pdf tool such as pdftotext to get a text file version then use perl or python or your preferred text tool to get the last bit of text on each page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run pdftotext on the pdf generated from the above you get a text file with pages separated by form feed (ctrl-L) that ends–

```
 Is this person doing something violent or not?
• Natural language processing (NLP) from digital documents:
– Does this news article belong to the realm of politics or sports?
– Does this query phrase match a particular article in the archive?

^L2

0.1.1

Second Level Head

Another instance of quantitative estimation is estimating a house’s price based
on inputs like current income of the house’s owner, crime statistics for the
neighborhood, and so on. Machines that make such quantitative estimators are
called regressors.

^L
```

So if you remove blank lines then grab each line that is the line above a form feed you get more or less the requested text:

```
$ sed -e '/^[ \t]*$/d' aa072.txt |grep -B1 -P "\x0C" 
– Does this query phrase match a particular article in the archive?

2
--
called regressors.
```

Comment: Much thanks for your detailed suggestion, will check and get back

Comment: sorry to ask, you mentioned that `pdftotext`, is that a `Python` script or some thing else? Please excuse my clarification doesn't have sense

Comment: it is a binary (from the poppler suite I think) it comes with cygwin. linux etc: same as pdfinfo or pdffonts utilities that are often mentioned on this site @MadyYuvi

Comment: Thanks, have installed the `pdftotext`, need one more clarification, you wrote a code start with `$ sed -e ...`, in which program I should run? (Sorry, if I asked basic question)

Comment: sorry `$` is just the default linux command prompt, the command used is `sed`

Comment: @MadyYuvi so `sed -e '/^[ \t]*$/d' YourFile.txt |grep -B1 -P "\x0C" `

Comment: Should I run this command in `Linux`?

Comment: I actually used a cygwin bash shell in windows, you can get sed for native windows as well (or use perl or python if you prefer) but sed is available by default in any unix like setting linux or cygwin or macos or ... @MadyYuvi

Comment: Thanks, it's more useful and really thanks a lot for your prompt and kind guidance